# wrt OCR Marking Scheme is this correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i'm trying to help my son with his a-level maths, it seems as if there is a particular way to answer the questions.

here is an example question -
[image]

here is the mark scheme -
[image]

and his answer -

dy/dx = 8x-x^-2

0 = 8x-x^-2

0.5=x

would he get full marks for this answer? it kind of looks right from inference.

can anyone offer any resource, tips, hints on how these papers are usually marked or any kind of mindset it would help to have when committing an answer?

sorry if this is the wrong forum, any suggested places to visit would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would mark this full. For exams like this, the graders are not looking to match their rubric exactly, but if the main parts are there.

Comment: This is exactly the correct answer following the method given with all steps of working shown. What part of it did you think could differ from the mark scheme, or what terminology in the mark scheme is causing confusion?

Comment: Someone overly nitpicky might insist that decimal numbers are always rounded results, so that $0.5$ would represent the range $0.45..0.55$, and that the correct notation is $x=\frac12$.

Comment: it was the middle section where is says "!their dy/dx=0 and 'correct step'" - but this is a poor example i guess.  oh and i'm not an examiner. thanks for your comment

Comment: Your son should write an answer that makes sense to him. If he feels an extra step or two or a bit of English in there will help him think more clearly, then he should do that. Try to produce something that if you look at it a few days later it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your particular query was about the steps "their $dy/dx=0$" and "correct step".

However, the notes in the RH column say that the relevant working can be "**seen or implied**".

Your son explicitly equates his $dy/dx$ to zero so there can be no doubt on that point.

He then omits any further working and gives the correct answer. He still receives the method mark DM1 because it is implied by his correct answer.

So your son deservedly receives full marks.

It is perhaps worthwhile noting that the purpose of the DM1 mark is to give partial credit to someone who applies a correct method to solve $$8x-1/x^2=0$$ but makes an error. In that sense putting in an extra line of working could be said to be 'safer'. Had your son been less accurate he would have lost two marks.